# Comparing and changing columns from different dataframe - Python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, compare

I have two files with columns that have different lengths that looks like this:

```
df2:  
  N_Machine       x       y       z
0     CB-32   90.42  910.29   62.68
1     CB-27  985.65  995.54  669.62
2     CB-18  852.92  952.51  525.60
3     CB-43  950.92  906.64  618.59

df:
    Name    Number
0   CB-15  12.55.47
1   CB-32  12.55.21
2   CB-91  12.55.75
3   CB-07  12.55.13
4   CB-22  12.55.14
5   CB-16  12.55.52
6   CB-43  12.55.49
7   CB-24  12.55.55
8   CB-17  12.55.31
9   CB-32  12.55.33
10  CB-38  12.55.19
11  CB-27  12.55.62
12  CB-51  12.55.23
13  CB-14  12.55.39
14  CB-31  12.55.65
15  CB-41  12.55.62
16  CB-20  12.55.70
17  CB-18  12.55.26
18  CB-10  12.55.44
```

What I've been doing is: trying to compare the columns df['Name'] and df2['N_ Machine']. If they are equal, df2['N_ Machine'] will receive the value of the column df['Number'] from the corresponding row.

For example, the line [0] of df2['N_Machine '] matches with df['Number] in line[1]. Then df2['N_Machine '] should receive the value '12.55.21' from df['Number]. So the line [0] of df2 would be changed to:

```
df:  
  N_Machine       x       y       z
0     12.55.21   90.42  910.29   62.68
```

My code is below. My question is: after compare the columns, df2['Machine'] is receiving the first values of df['Number'], instead of the df['Number'] values from the matching rows, how could I fix this?

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas

df = pandas.read_excel('Part_Dat.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')

df2 = pd.read_csv("Data_Aver_Coord.csv")

if [df['Name'].isin(df2['N_Machine'])]:
    df2['N_Machine']=df['Number']`
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pandas.DataFrame.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, left_on='N_Machine', right_on='Name', how='outer').drop(['N_Machine'], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df3
         x       y       z   Name    Number
0    90.42  910.29   62.68  CB-32  12.55.21
1    90.42  910.29   62.68  CB-32  12.55.33
2   985.65  995.54  669.62  CB-27  12.55.62
3   852.92  952.51  525.60  CB-18  12.55.26
4   950.92  906.64  618.59  CB-43  12.55.49
5      NaN     NaN     NaN  CB-15  12.55.47
6      NaN     NaN     NaN  CB-91  12.55.75
7      NaN     NaN     NaN  CB-07  12.55.13
8      NaN     NaN     NaN  CB-22  12.55.14
9      NaN     NaN     NaN  CB-16  12.55.52
10     NaN     NaN     NaN  CB-24  12.55.55
11     NaN     NaN     NaN  CB-17  12.55.31
12     NaN     NaN     NaN  CB-38  12.55.19
13     NaN     NaN     NaN  CB-51  12.55.23
14     NaN     NaN     NaN  CB-14  12.55.39
15     NaN     NaN     NaN  CB-31  12.55.65
16     NaN     NaN     NaN  CB-41  12.55.62
17     NaN     NaN     NaN  CB-20  12.55.70
18     NaN     NaN     NaN  CB-10  12.55.44
```